# System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code, when deleting user alerts?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I am getting `System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code` when deleting user alerts by programming. It is working good in my QA farm. But not working in DEV farm.

I added application pool account to farm administation group and database users group as `dbowner`. Still getting same error.

```
 protected void ChkBx41_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;       
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
     using(SPSite site=new SPSite(url.Text)){
      using (SPWeb eweb = site.OpenWeb())
      {
            SPUser juser = null;
            eweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            try
            {
              juser = eweb.AssociatedMemberGroup.Users[user.LoginName];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            if (ChkBx41.Checked)
            {

                if (juser == null)
                {
                  eweb.AssociatedMemberGroup.AddUser(eweb.EnsureUser(user.LoginName));
                  SPUtility.SendEmail(eweb, true, true, user.Email, "Welcome to " + eweb.Title, "Hello " + "<br><br>" + "Welcome to the " + eweb.Title + " ");
                  createalert(SPAlertFrequency.Daily, eweb, eweb.EnsureUser(user.LoginName),true);
             }
             RBList4.SelectedValue = "Daily";
             RBList4.Enabled = true;
           }
           else
           {
             if (juser != null)
             {
                eweb.AssociatedMemberGroup.RemoveUser(juser);
                removealert(eweb, juser);
                RBList4.SelectedValue = null;
                RBList4.Enabled = false;
             }

          }
      eweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
  }
});


}

    public void removealert(SPWeb rweb, SPUser ruser)
      {
        bool oldCatchAccessDeniedException = rweb.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException;
        try
        {
          SPUser cuser = rweb.EnsureUser(ruser.LoginName);
          List<Guid> altid = new List<Guid>();
          foreach (SPAlert alt in cuser.Alerts)
          {
            try
            {
              if (alt.AlertType == SPAlertType.List)
              {
                altid.Add(alt.ID);
              }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
          }
          rweb.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
          foreach (Guid delid in altid)
          {
            cuser.Alerts.Delete(delid);
          } 
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
          rweb.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException = oldCatchAccessDeniedException;
        }
       }
```

Comment: @James - from what context are you running this code? (How do you trigger it..?)

Comment: SPWeb rweb = new SPSite(url.Text).OpenWeb(). Is the way I am using.

Comment: What sort of authentication are you using?

Comment: @Dexter: I added whole code in the post.

Comment: @James123, I mean what type of authentication are you using on your web front end - integrated auth, Forms Authentication or anonymous?

Comment: it is Forms Based Authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running from web part, try elevating?

```
public void removealert(SPWeb rweb, SPUser ruser) {
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
        using(SPSite csite = new SPSite(rweb.Site.Id)) {
            using(SPWeb cweb = csite.OpenWeb(rweb.Id)) {
                SPUser cuser = cweb.EnsureUser(ruser.LoginName);    

                List<Guid> altid = new List<Guid>();
                foreach (SPAlert alt in cuser.Alerts) {
                    try {
                        if (alt.AlertType == SPAlertType.List) {
                            altid.Add(alt.ID);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception) {
                    }
                }
                foreach (Guid delid in altid) {
                    cuser.Alerts.Delete(delid);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I also would be interested to know where `SPWeb rweb` comes from. I hope not from SPContext, as you should not Dispose that.

I would recommend also having your SPWebs in a using block, in the same method block for easy reading.